# How do I retrieve records from two tables that use the same PK while singling out records with a specific PK entry?

Tags: sql, join

I have two tables joined by a primary key (coupon ID -as you can see in the attached  picture below).
In the coupon table I have all of the existing coupons .
In the customer coupon table I have coupon id's that have been purchased by the customer id next to it.
Only coupons that have been purchased appear in the customer coupon table.

I would like to send a query in which I can  retrieve all the coupons that have not been purchased by a certain customer ID. 
the retrieved records can be coupons that have been purchased by other customer id's or new coupons which don't appear in the customer coupon table.

I'm currently using a derby DB which supports the following:

- INNER JOIN
- LEFT OUTER JOIN
- RIGHT OUTER JOIN

[image: Two tables that are joined by ID(PK)]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most straight forward approach, IMHO, would be to use the `not exists` operator:

```
SELECT *
FROM   coupon c
WHERE  NOTE EXISTS (SELECT *
                    FROM   customer_coupon cc
                    WHERE  c.id = cc.coupon_id AND
                           cc.customer_id = 123 /* Just an example */)
```

Comment: Thanks!
I used String sql = "SELECT * FROM coupon c WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM   customer_coupon cc WHERE  c.id = cc.coupon_id AND  cc.customer_id ="+ customer.getId() +") AND c.amount > 0 AND c.end_date => '" + sqldateLimit + "'"; and it worked perfectly.